# R ellipsis - further arguments passed to or from other methods

Tags: r, ellipsis

I understand what dot-dot-dot means in general. I understand how to use it when I want to create my own function with unknown number of parameters.

I do not understand how it works for example at function `variable.names()`. When I execute `?variable.names`, there is written the following:

> ...    further arguments passed to or from other methods.

What does it really mean? I do not know what I can pass there. How and where will be these passed arguments used.

Comment: If you invoke `variable.names` without the parentheses, you'll see it's just a `UseMethod` call, which tells you it's [an S3 generic](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html). The generic will decide which specific method to call based on the class of the first argument. That method, e.g. `variable.names.lm`, may have more parameters, like `full`. That method also gets passed the remaining `...` from the generic, but if you look at its source code with `stats:::variable.names.lm`, it doesn't do anything at all with them.

Comment: Okay, thanks. But how do I know what parameters i can provide in `...`?

Comment: The documentation for `?variable.names.lm` (or whatever the relevant method is), which in that case happens to be right below the docs for the generic. In this case the only difference is `full`. The `...` to `variable.names.lm` are ignored, which you can only really see by looking at the source.

Comment: A better example would be `summary`, an S3 generic with a lot more methods, many of which with separate docs. Looking at `?summary` contains the info for some of them, but if you look at `methods(summary)`, you'll find a lot more, e.g. `?summary.glm`, which has different parameters that initially get passed though the generic's `...`. Again, the class of the first object passed in determines the relevant method.

Comment: Okay, so if I want to provide some arguments passed in `...`, I have to check appropriate method that will be called by this "default" method that takes `...` and see, what arguments it takes? Basically, in `...` I provide parameters for that one concrete method that will be called by this "default" method?

Comment: Yep, pretty much, except that the default method (e.g. `summary.default`) is the method the generic calls when there's no class-specific method. They're frequently used for simpler vectors, e.g. numerics, whereas complicated objects like models are much more likely to have their own methods.

Comment: Hadley's _Advanced R_ chapter on S3 that I linked in my first comment is a good reference that starts more from the beginning, if you need a more complete reference.

Comment: Good, will check that patiently. Thanks

Comment: Maybe `plot`is a better example. Imagine you have a function that does some processing and then plots a result. You would include a dots argument to be passed to `plot` in order to set titles, colors, etc (things you don't need that function to do).

Comment: @RuiBarradas In fact, this is not what I was looking for. In `plot`, there are those arguments written. In other functions they are not written and from where can you get them? You can just guess and try?

Comment: I have just looked at the source of `variable.names.lm` that is called when `object` is of class `lm` and it *does not* use the dots argument. If I understand your question correctly, the best way of knowing what parameters you can provide in `...` is to read the sources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ellipsis argument allows one to pass arguments to a downstream function. We'll illustrate with a simple R function as follows.

```
testfunc <- function(aFunction,x,...) {
     aFunction(x,...)
}
aVector <- c(1,3,5,NA,7,9,11,32)

# returns NA because aVector contains NA values
testfunc(mean,aVector)

# use ellipsis in testfunc to pass na.rm=TRUE to mean()
testfunc(mean,aVector,na.rm=TRUE)
```

...and the output:

```
> testfunc <- function(aFunction,x,...) {
+      aFunction(x,...)
+ }
> aVector <- c(1,3,5,NA,7,9,11,32)
> 
> # returns NA because aVector contains NA values
> testfunc(mean,aVector)
[1] NA
> # use ellipsis in testfunc to pass na.rm=TRUE to mean()
> testfunc(mean,aVector,na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 9.714286
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand what you mean by this but I still do not understand manual pages with `...`. How can I know what arguments I can provide to functions (i.e. `variable.names()` like I mentioned in my question). What are they for?

Comment: @scarface - the valid arguments for a function are listed in the function documentation. As @alistaire noted in his comments on the OP, `variable.names()` isn't a very relevant function for this discussion because the more concrete implementations of this interface (i.e. `variable.names.lm()` do not have any additional arguments that would be meaningful for `variable.names()` to pass along.